# constructor without initializer list having objects with deleted constructors

Tags: c++

I used to have my `CameraMill` class check if the size of the input params vector is correct and then initialize my cameras `m_cam0` and `m_cam1`

```
CameraMill::CameraMill(std::vector<camera::Params> params)
{
    if (params.size() == 2)
    {
        m_cam0 = Camera(params[0]);
        m_cam1 = Camera(params[1]);
    }
}
```

A recent change to the `Camera` class has deleted the constructor. So this fails with `error: use of deleted function`. I could initialize them in the initializer list but then I can't check the size...

```
CameraMill(std::vector<Params> params)
    : m_cam0(params[0])
    , m_cam1(params[1])
{
    // if (params.size() == 2)
    // {
    //  m_cam0 = Camera(params[0]);
    //  m_cam1 = Camera(params[1]);
    // }
}
```

How do I go about without using initializer list?

Comment: What should happen with `m_cam0` and `m_cam1` if you don't have 2 params?

Comment: Why not just make the constructor take two params?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I would initialize them with some default values further down in the constructor

Comment: Then can't you do `m_cam0(params.size() == 2 ? params[0] : default_value), ...`

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish the vector seemed cleaner to me at the time

Comment: Wouldn't the cleanest solution just be a constructor with no arguments and a constructor with two arguments?

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish Eventually I will have n cameras, with m params given to me (m <= n). So I initialize first m with input params, and rest with default.

Comment: I often use private class static function initializer helpers for data members that need more complicated behavior (such as throwing if some requirement isn't met... like vector having a size of 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper function to get the right `Param` object.

```
CameraMill(std::vector<Params> params) : 
   m_cam0(CameraMill::getParam(params, 0)),
   m_cam1(CameraMill::getParam(params, 1))
{
}
```

where

```
Params const& CameraMill::getParam(std::vector<Params> const& params, size_t i)
{
   return (i < params.size()) ? params[i] : Params();
}
```

#### Update

The above function results in undefined behavior. The temporary is destroyed at the end of the function call. Thanks, @Jarod42.

Other options:

1. Make the return type an object instead of a reference.

   ```
   Params CameraMill::getParam(std::vector<Params> const& params, size_t i)
   {
      return (i < params.size()) ? params[i] : Params();
   }
   ```
2. Have a function static variable and return it instead of a default constructed temporary object.

   ```
   Params const& CameraMill::getParam(std::vector<Params> const& params, size_t i)
   {
      static Params p;
      return (i < params.size()) ? params[i] : p;
   }
   ```

Comment: You return reference to temporary :/

Comment: @Jarod42. Yes. The temporary is used to initialize other objects. I believe the life of  the temporary will be extended until the constructor returns.

Comment: With `Param` return type, it would be ok, here you have UB, temporary ends with function. Inlining it manually to call site would be another alternative or provide defautl value as argument of `getParam`.

Answer (score 0):

> I could initialize them in the initializer list but then I can't check the size...

A workaround would be to call a function in the initializer list to perform the check and/or construct the objects, although that usually looks quite bad.

It would be simpler to simply call `.at()` instead, and then inside the body of the constructor check if the size was bad to begin with:

```
CameraMill(std::vector<Params> params)
    : m_cam0(params.at(0))
    , m_cam1(params.at(1))
{
    if (params.size() != 2)
        ...
}
```

Not a great solution either, but works.

The best, of course, is to either fix your constructor signature, revert the `Camera` class, or simply setup the `m_cam` objects after creating them "empty" (assuming you have a constructor for that).

Comment: using `at` will throw an exception -- I don't want to do that if params are not provided. I can initialize with defaults.

Comment: @simplename Well, of course, exceptions are the standard mechanism you report mistakes in constructors; that is why I suggested `at`. If `params` not being provided is not an error, then you need something else; the simplest being initializing the members with empty ones.